# Converting 1D array to 2D array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have a text file that looks like this:

```
0000001
0000002
0000003
0000004
0000005
0000006....
```

I am using the code below to convert 1d array to 2d..

```
$filename  = "surface.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
while(!feof($fp)) {  
     $content = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
     $lines = explode("\n", $content);
   for ($i=0; $i<=$row; $i++){
   for ($j =0; $j<=$col; $j++){
      //echo $lines[$i*$col + $j]; 
      $matrix[$i][$j] = $lines[$i*$col + $j];
      //var_dump($matrix[i][j]); 
     }
    }
   }
 fclose($fp);
```

My output array $matrix prints all NULL values.I have put var_dump() inside the loop to see what it displays.. Interestingly, It is reading all the values,but, after the last value, it kept on reading empty values too, which inturn made the $matrix empty(NULL) at last.
I don't know how to fix this problem. If I am not clear in explaining how the output appears, please look at it below..

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0000001 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0000002 [1] => 0000002 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0000001 [1] => 0000002 [2] => 0000003 ) )
```

In the last lines, I see that the output is like below

```
  Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] =>   [3] => ) [2] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) [3] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) [4] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) [5] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) [6] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) )
```

Any help is highly appreciated..

Comment: Where is `$col` defined? With the indexes for the `for` loops, you normally start on `$i = 0` and the comparison is `$i < $col`, then you'll compare as many members as numbers in `$col` (you start by 0).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728171/convert-1d-array-to-2d-array-and-join-php try

Comment: $row and $col are defined in the original file,, I forgot to paste it..Sorry..$row=6; $col=3; Thanks for looking into it

Comment: Then check out my suggestion. If there are 6 rows, you want `for ($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++)`. If you use the `<=` you'd have 7 rows, being the last one undetermined. Same with `$col`.

Comment: I did the correction and ran the code..it corrected the rows issue but, It is still dumping Null values.

Comment: Do you see any major fault with the code? I am not sure why it is not stopping at EOF..

Comment: did you try with `file_get_contents($filename)` ? like in _chiliNUT_ code bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work

```
  $filename="surface.txt"
 $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
 $content = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
 $lines = explode("\n", $content);
 for ($i=0; $i<$row; $i++){
 for ($j =0; $j<$col; $j++){

  $matrix[$i][$j] = $lines[$i*$col + $j];
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//asuming $row and $col are defined
//$row=5;
//$col=5;


$filename  = "surface.txt";

     $content = file_get_contents($filename);
     $lines=explode("\n",$content);
foreach ($lines as $rowNum=>$r)
{
$r=str_split($r);
if ($rowNum+1>$row)
break;    
if ($r===[""])
continue;
while (count($r)>$col)
{
array_pop($r);
}
$matrix[]=$r;
}
var_dump($matrix);
```

Comment: After adding $lines=str_split($lines); my output is all NULL :(

Comment: I assume the file is raw data, OP did not mention any characters in it not to process.

Comment: the text file has all token numbers..  I need to put it into a 2D array to be able to access each of the token.

Comment: did my edit work? if you really don't wanna process all data, and only want to process `$row` number of rows and `$col` number of cols I can show you how to do that too

Comment: Could you please check and see if it works? any syntax errors?

Comment: I fixed an off by one error. It runs, no syntax / logic errors

Comment: I don't know where the problem lies,,but, i am getting 500 internal server error.